# Expresiones Regulares en Python

Tags: html, python, regex

Estaba intentando extraer la información de un código de html, en concreto lo que me interesa es centrarme en el contenido de esta etiqueta de html:

```
<h2> <a href="https://www.xataka.com/robotica-e-ia/deepfakes-tendremos-problema-verdad-videos-serviran-como-pruebas" class="l:3035280" > Con los deepfakes tendremos un problema con la verdad: ni los vídeos servirán como pruebas </a>  </h2>
```

Lo que quiero es quedarme con la información que está entre la etiqueta `h2`, ya que después pensaba filtrar lo que realmente me interesa que es la frase "Con los deepfakes tendremos un problema con la verdad: ni los vídeos servirán como pruebas" que pensaba hacer con un re.search.

He intentado coger `[\s\w]+<\/h2>` pensando en quedarme con todas las letras y espacios a los que les preceda la etiqueta `</h2>` pero no logro conseguir el resultado que deseo.

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. Debes [edit] y mejorar tu pregunta. Agrega en la pregunta qué has intentado, qué errores tienes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque la pregunta llevaba el tag `regexp`, también llevaba el tag `python`, por lo que voy a dar otra solución que no usa expresiones regulares (Pues considero que la respuesta de Julio ya cubre perfectamente ese caso).

En general, parsear HTML mediante expresiones regulares es algo complejo, y da lugar a un código frágil, difícil de leer y de mantener.

Es preferible usar herramientas específicamente diseñadas para parsear HTML y acceder al "DOM" (modelo de documento) resultante, como por ejemplo `lxml` y `xpath`. Por desgracia esta utilidad no viene preinstalada con Python, por lo que tendrás que instalarla con `pip install` (preferiblemente dentro de un entorno virtual). Una vez instalada podrás usarla por ejemplo en la forma siguiente:

```
import lxml.html

html="""
<h2> <a href="https://www.xataka.com/robotica-e-ia/deepfakes-tendremos-problema-verdad-videos-serviran-como-pruebas" class="l:3035280" > Con los deepfakes tendremos un problema con la verdad: ni los vídeos servirán como pruebas </a>  </h2>
<p> Este texto está fuera del h2 </p>
<h2> <b><u> Con los Deepfakes... </u></b> </h2>
"""

dom =lxml.html.fromstring(html)
for h2 in dom.xpath("//h2"):
  print("Contenido:", h2.text_content().strip())
```

Y obtendrías:

```
Contenido: Con los deepfakes tendremos un problema con la verdad: ni los vídeos servirán como pruebas
Contenido: Con los Deepfakes...
```

La expresión `"//h2"` que le he pasado a Xpath significa "cualquier elemento de tipo `h2` que aparezca en el documento, sin importar el nivel de anidamiento en que aparezca". Esa expresión selecciona todos los elementos `h2` del documento, con todo lo que contengan. El método `text_content()` extrae lo que es el puro texto sin marcar dentro de esos elementos.

Otra biblioteca que se usa a menudo para *parsear* html es [Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) que tiene una sintaxis quizás más amigable (pero a diferencia de XPath no es un estándar). Con esta biblioteca se haría así:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for h2 in soup.find_all("h2"):
  print("Contenido:", h2.get_text().strip())
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con lo siguiente: `<h2>(?:\s*<[^>]+>)*\s*(.*?)\s*(?:<\/[^>]+>\s*)*<\/h2>` Debería funcionar con cualquier etiqueta o etiquetas que haya dentro de `<h2>`

Como:

- `<h2><a href="..."> Foo Bar </a></h2>`
- `<h2><u><b><i> Foo Bar </i></b></u></h2>`
- Etcétera

En el grupo de captura 1 tendrás el texto sin etiquetas.

Ver ejemplo/demo: https://regex101.com/r/4A0kc4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Si estás interesado en el texto "Con los deepfakes tendremos un problema con la verdad: ni los vídeos servirán como pruebas", lo que en realidad **necesitas es la información de la etiqueta `<a>`** (no de `<h2>`).

Y lo puedes realizar de la siguiente forma:

```
texto = "<h2> <a href=\"https://www.xataka.com/robotica-e-ia/deepfakes-tendremos-problema-verdad-videos-serviran-como-pruebas\" class=\"l:3035280\" > Con los deepfakes tendremos un problema con la verdad: ni los vídeos servirán como pruebas </a>  </h2>"

import re
reg = '\<a.*\>(.*)\<\/a\>'
m = re.search(reg, texto)

print(m.group(1))
```

Aquí está el enlace por si deseas realizar más pruebas con ese Regex: https://regex101.com/r/y4yd59/1

Comment: Creo que no se acaba de ajustar a lo que pide la pregunta porque estás buscando dentro de cualquier etiqueta `<a>`, y eso podría buscar cosas que no interesen a OP. OP pedía buscar en `<h2>`, así que se debería buscar dentro de `<a>` dentro de `<h2>`